# How to display image in it's original state in Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-blade

I uploaded different images of the product the problem is when I display it in a blade file it shows inverted not in the original form. See the Image below.
[image: Left side the uploaded images and the Right side is the original picture]

In the above image on the right side is the original image when I upload it and display the images it shows inverted on the left side.
How to resolve it??

Thanks!

Comment: Your computer rotates the image based on EXIF data contained within the image, which is placed there by the camera, which uses sensors to determine when the camera was rotated sideways. I've linked a duplicate indicating how to correct this with PHP; there's also a neat Laravel-compatible package that does it for you. http://image.intervention.io/api/orientate

Comment: Thanks, dear @ceejayoz, but in my case, I am getting the array of product details in which one of the attributes is an image then how to resolve it?

Comment: If the image comes from you, you can pre-process it to rotate correctly. If the image is a URL under someone else's control, you may need to write code to download and correct it, or use a service like https://imgix.com/ that does it for you.